# Can't see Ubuntu on Boot Menu as an option. I can see only Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

I have an ASUS TUF A15 Windows laptop and recently I installed Ubuntu(23.10) alongside Windows 11 as a Dual boot. From the time I installed Ubuntu, I had issues lining up. I am very new to Ubuntu so I am trying to figure out everything on my own.

So now, the actual problem is I cannot see Ubuntu as an option on my Boot menu to get into Ubuntu OS. On my Grub Screen, I can only see Windows. I saw a few tips on the internet and one of them was to disable "Fast startup". I did that from Windows as well as from the UFI firmware settings. I attaching a picture of my boot menu. Please help.

I also urge anyone to help me get to know if any things should be done for sure after installing Ubuntu. Like any software, libraries, or any other thing will help run Ubuntu smoothly.

[image: My_Grub_Menu]

Comment: Have you tried boot repair?: https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/1004020

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Boot repair solved the issue DanielT, Thank you.

By the time I saw your comment, I already performed the boot repair and clicked the auto fix. Sorry for that and I'll remember this in the future if something happens. Thanks for inputs @oldfred

Comment: The situation was little different. Windows was already installed. I installed ubuntu alongside windows. Then after few days I couldn't see Ubuntu on the Boot screen to launch it. While in the link you mentioned, even though not seeing the Ubuntu is the problem for both of us, he installed Windows recently and cannot see Ubuntu. I don't know if these 2 situations are same.

Nevertheless, the suggested solution was Boot repair and it worked well.